# Настройка proxy_pass в nginx в Plesk

Tags: nginx, centos7, proxypass

Не могу настроить nginx. Сервер работает на CentOS 7, также работает Plesk (вдруг он как-то мешает).
Пытаюсь в файле /etc/nginx/nginx.conf прописать следующее:

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server{
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/crt.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/key.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Однако после перезапуска nginx буквально ничего не меняется. Единственное, что когда синтаксис нарушаю, сервер выдаёт следующее:

> Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

Comment: Так а что должно поменяться?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Насколько понимаю, должно быть проксирование на 6000 порт. Но его не происходит